# Will the listeners be removed when we call $.remove() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, listeners

...

There are listeners on $('#target') and its children.

When we call $('#target').remove() to delete it from DOM,will the listeners be removed?

If not,how to remove them together?

Answer (score 5):

Depends on how you add the listeners. If you do

```
$("#target").click(function() { doSomething(); });
```

Then `remove()` will also delete the listener. However, if you do:

```
$("#target").live("click", function() { doSomething(); });
```

The listener will not be removed. What you've done here is to create a live HTML collection, and if you at a later point add a new element with id of "target", it will get this listenere added to it.

Comment: In my application,some listeners are added by html files loaded by $.load(),will they be removed?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the directly bound event handlers and the internally cached data will be removed.

From [Manipulation/remove](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/remove):

> "Note that this function starting with
>   1.2.2 will also remove  all event handlers and internally cached data."

Comment: What about the listeners added by html file loaded by $.load()?